# Add a number to an ascii string in C language

Tags: c

I have a string in C and I need to add +1 to every character in the string. For example, I want `abc def` to become `bcd efg`. I want to run it as `abc def | ./myprog`

This is the code I have, and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char stringline[200];
    char result[200];
    int lengthofstr;
    int i;

    scanf("%s", &stringline);
    lengthofstr = strlen(stringline);
    for(i=0; i < stringline; i++) {
        stringline[i] = (stringline[i] + 1);
    }
    printf("%s", stringline);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might explain what the problem is: what output did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: `abc def | ./myprog` will try to execute a program named `abc`, with the argument `def`, and pipe the output of *that* into `./myprog`.  I don't think that's what you want to do, even if your program worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe add your string to a file and pipe `cat file` into your program.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<stringline;i++)` should give you a warning along the lines of *[...] makes integer from pointer without a cast [...]*. You want `i < lengthofstr` [hint: in the future, always compile with `-Wall`]. Also, you probably want to test it as `echo -n "abc def" | ./myprog`. Last but not least, you'd also get a warning about `result` being defined but not used.

Comment: You are being optimistic about the size of the input. What happens if a user enters a string with more than 199 characters?

Comment: Or 2800 malicious characters. Do NOT use `"%s"` alone as the `scanf` format string. You might as well use `gets()`. They are essentially the same from a security risk standpoint. Limit the characters you will read. (e.g. `"%25s"`, whatever you need)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical typo. Replace

```
for(i=0;i<stringline;i++){
```

with

```
for(i=0;i<lengthofstr;i++){
```

Comment: Using the wrong variable isn't a typo; misspelling it would be a typo.

Comment: @ScottHunter It depends. As for me pressing the `s` key instead of `l` and `Ctrl+Space`ing it then is a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Compare with the length of the string, not with the array itself

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char stringline[200];
    int lengthofstr;
    int i;

    scanf("%199s", &stringline);
    lengthofstr = strlen(stringline);
    for(i=0;i<lengthofstr;i++){     // Modify HERE
        stringline[i] = (stringline[i] + 1);
    }
    printf("%s", stringline);

    return 0;
}
```

You were comparing with a pointer which will always be true

Comment: Also, `result` is unused.

Comment: Also, `%s` can cause a buffer overflow. Use `%199s` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicating the logic with `scanf` and format specifiers, etc., you could just read a character at a time from `stdin` and add `'1'` if it is an alphabetical character. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 200

int main (void) {

    int c;
    int idx = 0;
    char result[MAXC] = {0};

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && idx < MAXC) {
        if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')) c++;
        result[idx++] = c;
    }

    printf ("\n result: %s\n\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ echo "abc def" | ./bin/stdinplus1

 result: bcd efg
```

It also has the added benefit of leaving non `A-Za-z` characters unchanged:

```
$ echo "abc/def*g = hij" | ./bin/stdinplus1

 result: bcd/efg*h = ijk
```